# Product of disjoint cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've found the question to find product cycle of let be $\phi$ = (2, 4, 9, 7,) (6, 4, 2, 5, 9) (1, 6) (3, 8, 6) in S9. I know how to express the permutation of S9 as product of disjoint cycle, like the identity of S9 can be expressed by (1)(2), But I've 2 point that I don't really understand of this question.

1. Why we must express $\phi$ as a product of disjoint cycle again, while (2, 4, 9, 7,) (6, 4, 2, 5, 9) (1, 6) (3, 8, 6) is "disjoint cycle" itself.
2. In the first cycle 2 ---> 4, but in the second 2 ---> 5, I don't understand.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Disjoint cycles means that every cycle must contain numbers not in any other cycle. It seems that the question wants you to write (2 4 9 7)(6 4 2 5 9)(1 6)(3 8 6) in terms of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Okay, so my 1st and 2nd point of my confuse is done. But how about express it into disjoint cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The permutation $\phi \in S_9$ is the product of those four cycles, which are *not* disjoint.  Thinking of permutations as bijective functions from a set of nine elements back to itself, the product is a composition.

Consider the number $1$.  Reading the cycles from right to left (as functions) and noting that a number is fixed if it's not mentioned in a cycle, we get
$$
1 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 9
$$
so $\phi(1) = 9$.  Now, what is $\phi(9)$?  Continue like that until you get back to $1$.  This will be one of the disjoint cycles in $\phi$.

Comment: Can you finish that cycle?  I can give more hints if you need.

Comment: Still I don't get it.

Comment: Perfect, (1 9 6 3 8) (2 5 7), I get it we can reading from the right or left, if we read from left we get (1 3 8 6 4)(2)(5 9 7) like Vladhagen answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use my above comment as an answer, they want to to take the cycles

$$(2 4 9 7)(6 4 2 5 9)(1 6)(3 8 6)$$

and write them as disjoint cycles.

So, going from left to right $$1\rightarrow 6 \rightarrow3$$ $$2\rightarrow4\rightarrow2$$
$$3 \rightarrow8$$ $$4 \rightarrow 9 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow1$$
$$5 \rightarrow9$$ $$6 \rightarrow4$$
$$7 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow5$$
$$8\rightarrow6$$
$$9 \rightarrow7$$

So, all told we have $$(1 3 8 6 4)(2)(5 9 7)$$ in disjoint cycle notation.

Comment: This depends entirely on whether you want to act on the right or the left or course, as the answer below suggests.

Comment: I understand your step.
But its answer is (1,9,6,3,8)(2,5,7), I don't really understand. In the book itself doesn't give explanation.
Or maybe i just said the site : <www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/soln23.html#s2315>

Comment: Yes, Sammy's answer is the one you want then.

Answer (score 0):

1 > 1 > 6 > 4 > 9

9 > 9 > 9 > 6 > 6

6 > 3 > 3 > 3 > 3

3 > 8 > 8 > 8 > 8

8 > 6 > 1 > 1 > 1

thus we have (19638)

2 > 2 > 2 > 5 > 5

5 > 5 > 5 > 9 > 7

7 > 7 > 7 > 7 > 2

thus we have (257)

and together we have (19638)(257)

which is a product of disjoint cycles